# Automate web page access and fill web form using Java

Tags: java

There is a website that I need to use often.
In this website, I need to repeat a sequence of steps.
I want to write a program that automates this process (I have more practice with Java, but it can be in any language).

I tried Selenium, but it opens the browser and simulates user commands, I want something that can run in background.

Steps:
 1. Login
 2. Select item in menu
 3. Insert client's code
 4. Select item in menu
 5. Click a button
 6. Insert product's codes
 7. Back to step 2

Thanks.

Comment: Which browser do you want to run this in?

Comment: you could use your browser network (STRG+SHIFT+I) tab to track the request when you submit the form.
Then you can imitate the form submit with a [Post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) reqeust (assuming the site doesn't use ssl)

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html

Comment: you can use selenium in headless mode https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=running%20selenium%20headless